# How many subgraphs with exactly 6 edges can I make from a complete graph with 7 vertices?

Tags: trees, planar-graphs

Let the complete graph be unweighted and undirected. The subgraphs can be unconnected.

Edit (More detail): I'm trying to go about this by splitting it up into spanning trees and non-spanning trees because spanning trees also have 6 edges. Therefore...

# of subgraphs with 6 edges = # of Spanning Trees + # of Non-Spanning Tree with 6 edges

The number of spanning trees is equal to $V^{V-2} = 7^5=16807$ where V is the number of vertices. So, I need to find the number of non-spanning trees, but I don't know where to go from there.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think I fixed it, but let me know if there is anything unclear.

Comment: Are you asking about labelled or unlabelled subgraphs?  That is, are two subgraphs considered the same if they are isomorphic?

Comment: Sorry, they are labeled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are overthinking this. It's just the number of ways to choose $6$ edges from the $(7 \times 6 )/ 2$ edges in the complete graph.

Comment: You're right. I was being dumb. This is just $\binom{21}{6}$

Comment: @ChrisHacen Not dumb. Starting down a bad path happens a lot.  And now you have a count for the nontrees, by subtracting.